# How to import CSV file data into my database using pandas and pyodbc?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

import the package

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
```

building the connection

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; Server=servername; Database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=Yes")
cur = conn.cursor()
```

save the SQL code that build the table

```
string = "CREATE TABLE TESTDATA(Log int PRIMARY KEY, User varchar(15))"

tablename = re.search("CREATE TABLE ([a-z A-Z]+)\(",string)
if tablename:
    tablename = tablename.group(1)
```

if the table name are not in the sql table list then build the table

```
if not cur.table(table=tablename).fetchone():
    cur.execute(string)
    conn.commit()
```

read the data.csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv")
df.to_sql(name="TESTDATA", con=conn, index=True, index_label="id")
```

**File example**

**data.csv:**

```
Log  User
1    Jack
2    Jackie
3    Jacky
```

*I wish to import these data into the SQL Database but it fail*

*I not sure where goes wrong but it successful build the table out and fail to reading the csv file into the table*

Comment: You've given us some code, that's great. You've not said where you are stuck, though. As it stands, the question is likely to be closed, as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Oops, you managed to put most of the worst received things in your first question: code only, no context, no explainations for the why odbc and pandas, no description of the error of problem and code was not formatted... You really should read [ask] to understand how to edit this question to at least address my 3 first remarks, eventually add other improvements and be able to ask far better questions in future :-)

Comment: Why did you revert the formatting as code? It is hard to read without it:..

Comment: Does your CSV file really have spaces on either side of the comma delimiter, i.e., `Log , User` as opposed to `Log,User` ...?

Comment: It suppose is column by column not in this format. I don't know how to display at here.

Comment: @JackLim - I have formatted the "data.csv" sample data. Please confirm that your CSV data looks just like that (with [space][comma][space]), or [edit] the question to show the actual format.

Comment: `MySQL <> SQL Server` and *SQL Database* is not specific enough. Please fix inconsistency in title and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"CSV" is an acronym for "comma-separated values". Unfortunately nowadays the term "CSV" is applied to almost any text file containing data, even those that do not use commas as the field separator.

Still, many utilities assume a comma separator unless told otherwise. pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method is one of those:

> sep : str, default ‘,’

So for a text file containing

```
Log  User
1    Jack
2    Jackie
3    Jacky
```

the code

```python
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\data.txt")
print(df.to_dict())
```

produces

```
{'Log  User': {0: '1    Jack', 1: '2    Jackie', 2: '3    Jacky'}}
```

Note that there is only one column named `'Log  User'`, and each row contains the entire line from the text file.

If you want to parse that file correctly you'll need to use

```python
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\data.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
```